# MySQL: can an inner join be used in an update within a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql

Here's my code I'm trying to get working to no avail:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`auser`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `listings_set_image`(
  IN inPropertyId INT, IN inImage VARCHAR(150), IN inCaption(255))
BEGIN
  INNER JOIN    property_images pi
    ON pi.image_id = i.image_id
  UPDATE images i SET i.image_name = inImage, i.image_caption = inCaption 
  WHERE pi.property_id = inPropertyId;
END//
```

What am I not doing properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html) syntax is incorrect; the join should form part of ***`table_references`***:

```
UPDATE images i JOIN property_images pi USING (image_id)
SET    i.image_name = inImage, i.image_caption = inCaption
WHERE  pi.property_id = inPropertyId;
```